# str object not callable error when working with class inheritence in python

Tags: python

this type of question has been asked many times on this site but not in this scenario. Let me give you some context. I am just learning class inheritance and OOP in python3. I am working on a small Employee super class with a couple sub-classes. (Developer and Manager). The manager can have a list of employees that are from the Employee class (or they can be developers or even other managers as long as they are under the Employee class). This was going fine until I tried a
`print_emp` statement. Here is my code for the Manager Class:

```
class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, pay, employees=None):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, pay)
        if employees == None:
            self.employees = []
        else:
            self.employees = employees

    def add_employee(self, Employee):
        if Employee not in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(Employee)

    def del_employee(self, Employee):
        if Employee in self.employees:
            self.employees.remove(Employee)

    def print_emp(self):
        for emp in self.employees:
            name = emp._full_name()
            print(name)
```

This is my code for the Employee Class:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, pay):
        self.pay = pay
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = first_name + '.' + last_name + '@email.com'
        self.full_name = first_name + ' ' + last_name

    def pay_raise(self, raisepercent):
        self.pay = self.pay * (raisepercent / 100)
```

The error is 'str object not callable' on the lines

```
name = emp._full_name()
            print(name)
```

I have tried to fix it with normal methods like the `emp._full_name()` instead of `emp.full_name()` But I have been unsucessful so far. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `emp._full_name` is an attribute error. `emp.full_name` is indeed a string, as you explicitly set it. Why the parentheses?

Comment: Removing the parentheses and making ```emp._full_name``` into ```emp.full_name```

Comment: All that does is return the error ```'list' object is not callable``` on this line: ```man1.employees()```

Comment: Well why *would* it be callable?! It's a *list*. Stop trying to call everything!

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need the parenthesis after `emp._full_name`. Since it’s not a function or an object there is nothing to call. One good way to check the type of it is to run `type(emp._full_name)`. This should show that it is a string.

Comment: Not really helpful. Just fixed it by my own accord. I changed the function name because it was a name of a variable in Employee class